# Perform awk command on same file in many folders and append output

Tags: shell, awk

I have 40 folders (COPD1...COPD40) all that have a file called summary.txt. I want to extract the last element of the last line (e.g. "90%") in all of these folders. I know how to do this once :

```
awk '/Overall alignment rate:/{print $NF}' summary.txt
```

I am not sure how to do this for all 40 folders and append that extracted element to a new .txt file so the final product looks like:

```
COPD1 98%
COPD2 96%
...
COPD40 97.5%
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: To print the last field of the last line of a file is `awk '{p=$NF} END{print p}' file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/Overall alignment rate:/{print FILENAME,$NF}' COPD*/summary.txt
COPD1/summary.txt 90%
COPD2/summary.txt 90%
COPD3/summary.txt 90%
[...snip...]
```

Notes:

1. Awk has a variable, `FILENAME`, that is the current file name.
2. The shell glob `COPD*/summary.txt` will expand to all files named `summary.txt` that are in a directory that starts with `COPD`.

#### Documentation

From the [POSIX spec for awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> **FILENAME**
>  A pathname of the current input file. Inside a BEGIN
>   action the value is undefined. Inside an END action the value shall be
>   the name of the last input file processed.